# FormName.Show () is not working in VS 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Whenever I'm trying to close a window by switching/proceeding to another form, it does not show the window as per code. There are no errors, and I've tried using Build too but isn't working.

Here's where it is appearing:

```
 Public Class LoginForm
     Private Sub BtnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
         If (IsFormValid()) Then
             qr = "Select * from UserLogin where UserName='" & UsernameText.Text & "' And Password ='" & PasswordText.Text & "'"
             ds = SearchData(qr)
             If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
                 DashboardForm.Show()  ' ***Problem is here***
                 Me.Close()
             Else
                 MsgBox("Username and Passowrd is not correct", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
             End If
         End If
     End Sub
     Private Function IsFormValid() As Boolean
         If (UsernameText.Text.Trim() = String.Empty) Then
             MsgBox("Username is required", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
             UsernameText.Clear()
             PasswordText.Clear()
             Return False
 
         End If
 
         If (PasswordText.Text.Trim() = String.Empty) Then
             MsgBox("Password is required", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
             UsernameText.Clear()
             PasswordText.Clear()
             Return False
         End If
         Return True
     End Function
 
 
 End Class
```

The DashboardForm is where the user will be proceeded with, after logging in. The issue is the thing that when I put username and password correctly, the Login Form is closing itself indicating that the debugging is completed, and no form appears afterward.

I tried removing Me.Close() and it is now working but the Login Form is still there.

Comment: The issue is in line: 6, at Dashboard.Show(), which isn't getting executed but closes itself.

Comment: Is LoginForm the startup form for your app?  If so, closing that will close the app too

Comment: You are almost certainly going about this in the wrong way. It looks like `DashboardForm` is the main form for the application but `LoginForm` is the startup form. That's wrong. `DashboardForm` should be the startup form. You should be handling the `Startup` event of the application and displaying `LoginForm` there as a modal dialogue. The `LoginForm` doesn't display the `DashboardForm`. It just performs the login and then returns a `DialogResult` value indicating the result. If it fails, set `e.Cancel` to `True` and the application will exit without displaying the startup form. That's it.

Comment: [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?499888)'s one I prepared earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project properties
[image]
On the Application tab be sure Shutdown mode is "When last form closes"